# TypeScript never type inference

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Can someone please explain me why given the following code:

```
let f = () => {
    throw new Error("Should never get here");
}

let g = function() { 
    throw new Error("Should never get here");
}

function h() { 
    throw new Error("Should never get here");
}
```

The following types are inferred:

- `f` is `() => never`
- `g` is `() => never`
- `h` is `() => void`

I would expect the type of `h` to be `() => never` as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Great question. The difference is that `f` and `g` are function *expressions*, where `h` is a function *declaration*. When a function is `throw`-only, it gets the type `never` if it's an expression, and `void` if it's a declaration.

Surely the above paragraph doesn't actually help. Why is there a difference in behavior between a function expression and a function declaration? Let's look at some counter-examples in each case.

#### Bad idea #1: Make throwing function expressions return `void`

Consider some code:

```
function iif(value: boolean, whenTrue: () => number, whenFalse: () => number): number {
    return value ? whenTrue() : whenFalse();
}
let x = iif(2 > 3,
  () => { throw new Error("haven't implemented backwards-day logic yet"); },
  () => 14);
```

Is this code OK? It should be! It's common to write a `throw`ing function when we believe the function shouldn't be called, or should only be called in error cases. If the type of the function expression were `void`, though, the call to `iif` would be rejected.

So it's clear from this example that function expressions which only `throw` ought to return `never`, not `void`. And really this should be our default assumption, because these functions fit the definition of `never` (*in a correctly-typed program, a value of type `never` cannot be observed*).

#### Bad idea #2: Make throwing function declarations return `never`

After reading the prior section, you should be saying "Great, why don't all throwing functions return `never`, then?"

The short answer is it turned out to be a big breaking change to do so. There's a lot of code out there (especially code predating the `abstract` keyword) that looks like this

```
class Base {
    overrideMe() {
        throw new Error("You forgot to override me!");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    overrideMe() {
        // Code that actually returns here
    }
}
```

But a function returning `void` can't be substituted for a function returning `never` (remember, in a correctly-typed program, `never` values cannot be observed), so making `Base#overrideMe` return `never` prevents `Derived` from providing any non-`never` implementation of that method.

And generally, while function *expressions* that always throw often exist as sort of placeholders for `Debug.fail`, function *declarations* that always throw are very rare. Expressions frequently get aliased or ignored, whereas declarations are static. A function *declaration* that `throw`s today is actually likely to do something useful tomorrow; in the absence of a return type annotation, the safer thing to provide is `void` (i.e. don't look at this return type yet) rather than `never` (i.e. this function is a black hole that will eat the current execution stack).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Do you think that it is likely that all throwing functions return never in the future?

Comment: Well you can always add an explicit never return type to a function declaration.

Comment: Bad idea #3: trying to do class-based OOP in JS 