# TypeScript infers void instead of never on function statement

Tags: typescript

TypeScript infers `() => never` for `foo` if it's the result of a function expression which doesn't return:

```
const foo = function () {
  throw new Error();
}
```

But `void` if `foo` is a function statement:

```
function foo() {
  throw new Error();
}
```

I don't get it. Would be great to have an explanation.

Comment: Different syntax different behavior ? ‍♀️ It is strange though

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251524/typescript-never-type-inference

Comment: tldr: backwards compatibility. If a function in a class is inferred to return `never` then a child class can't provide an implementation which returns something else.

Answer (score -2):

Find the explanation in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).

"Never is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns"

The const foo will never be assigned if the assignation throws a error.