# Why can I assign void to a never-returning function

Tags: typescript, error-handling, eslint

Using `typescript 4.1.2` with `strict: true`, I can declare a function like this without any complaints from the compiler:

```js
function someFunction(): void {
  throw Error(`y so salty?`);
}
```

In my understanding, this function should be typed as returning [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never). I am quite surprised the compiler does not complain about `void` here.

After all, it makes a *huge* difference when calling the function. Anything after a `never`-returning function call will be unreachable code, which is not the case for `void`. I'd certainly like to know about that difference.

- What's the reason for TS being so lax here?
- Can I prevent this kind of behavior via the TS config?
- (bonus) is there – or could there even be – an `eslint` rule to cover this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251524/typescript-never-type-inference

Comment: Close to a duplicate, I agree, thanks a lot for pointing me to it. Still hoping for an answer on how to prevent this though :)

Comment: The answer in the linked question already explain why the warning will warn on very normal code.

Comment: @panepeter did not find any eslint rules. It is looks like you should explicitly type every function