Why TypeScript infers arrow functions and normal functions differently when they both throw errors
Consider the following two functions:
function throwError() {
  throw new Error()
}

const throwError2 = () => {
  throw new Error()
}

The first one gets inferred with a void return type, and the second one gets never. Why is that?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251524/typescript-never-type-inference
